# A person who doesn't get worried

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word/phrase meaning a person not getting worried or not hurrying in situations where most people do and get butterflies.

For example, you want to go on a trip by train. You've got your tickets and there is 15 minutes left to catch your train. Your husband or wife doesn't seem worried at all and keep saying "there is no rush." And you're all like *are you kidding me?!* and you say

> How can you be so relaxed?! You're such a [the word/phrase]!

Or you have a test and you need to study but you all seem so casual like you have all the time in the world. Your mum sees you and says

> You're really a [the word/phrase]! I'd study harder if I were you!

As you see this is what normally people get suprised by so I need a word with a negative connotation. Adjectives are also OK.

Thanks

Comment: Allowing a greater latitude to the term, *carefree*, *nonchalant*, *insouciant*, *unworried*, *relaxed*, *easy-going*, *laid-back* could possibly fit (as adjectives).

Comment: I'd add the adjectives _unaffected_, _unmoved_, and of course _cool_  to the list.

Comment: A somewhat related term is [procrastinator](http://he.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=procrastinator).

Comment: The other two are  _placid_ and _calm_, .

Comment: Thank you all. Which one is more common based on the context I put up there? I mean what a native speaker would say. "You are so nonchalant/placid/insouciant, etc". Or you simply rephrase it and use a different wording? What is natural to say?

Comment: [Sangfroid](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sangfroid): composure or coolness shown in danger or under trying circumstances. But I don't think it has a negative connotation. I also don't think this is perfect for describing what you are looking for. And it's pretty "heavy" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want negative connotation

> How can you be so relaxed?! You just **can't be bothered** can you?
>   You're really **can't be bothered**! I'd study harder if I were you!

which means not to care with indifferent attitude.

Something which is neutral in connotation

> How can you be so relaxed?! You're such a **non worrier**!  You never worry about anything.

Another alternative is

> How can you be so relaxed?! You're so **laid back**!  You never worry about anything.
>   You're really too **laid back**! I'd study harder if I were you!

which implies very easy going.